# I can't work out how to make validation work on an MVC Ajax modal box

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I am using JQM to produce AJAX modal boxes.

I have a normal page, and on that page, I have a link that launches the Ajax model box.

The Ajax modal launches fine, and it simply has a textbox and a button.

The model behind it has `Required` on that textbox, but, I can't figure out how to implement validation on it.

Currently, if there is text in the box, everything works fine and the box gets hidden. If there isn't any text in the box, I currently just `return null` from the controller and the box still gets hidden.

The final Ajax page with the form has the following code:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions    {
    UpdateTargetId = "TheBigList",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    OnSuccess = "HideModal",
    HttpMethod = "post",
    OnFailure = "AjaxError",

}))
{
    @Html.TextBox("text")

    <input type="submit" value="OK" />

}<br />
<br />
```

I hope this is straight forward and I will happily provide other code, but as it doesn't work, I am not sure how relevant it is! `HideModal` is just as it says, and I know `OnFailure` deals with connection rather than validation (I have thought about returning an error code to cheat!), but, I have tried many combinations that I have read on this site wihtout much luck.

The closest I though was by implementing `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#form0");` , However, I can't work out where/how to add this.

This has been driving me mad for the past week! Please help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

1) The client side validation via AJAX is pretty simple. You mode is set up in right way with the required attribute set.

2) Next thing you need to do is include the following scripts in the view :-

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

3) Setup the validation for the control in this way :-

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.TextBox)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Textbox)
```

**Note:-** You might need to change the properties passed in EditorFor and ValidationMessageFor

Hope it helps !!

Comment: This page has these two files loaded by the page that loads the model (that code sample was for the popup), I thought that would be enough... I am just going to try adding them now again to the ajax modal...

Comment: I have just tried, but, I can't get this to work :( I am pretty sure that this issue is related to the fact that the form is dynamically/Ajax loaded as I have been able to get unobtrusive validation working fine for non Ajax loaded elements.

Comment: can you please provide the code for action method. Also tell to which model it is strongly typed to

Comment: It is strongly typed to a simple model that just has one property "text" which is a string and has required. I don't think the controller matters as it seems to work fine, and, I am trying to get validation working before anything hits the controller.

Comment: try adding this after the using statement `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`